# Unable to upload Fortify results to SSC server using the IntelliJ plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, fortify

I have the Fortify Analysis plugin v19.1.2.0007 installed in IntelliJ.

I ran the following commands to add my Fortify SSC server certificate to my Fortify and JDK keystores, as mentioned [here](https://community.microfocus.com/t5/Fortify-User-Discussions/The-HP-Fortify-SSC-server-could-not-be-contacted-Please-check/td-p/1575063):

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Fortify\Fortify_SCA_and_Apps_19.1.2\jre\bin"
keytool.exe -import -alias SSC -keystore ..\lib\security\cacerts -file "c:\users\me\documents\fortify_mycompany_com.crt" -trustcacerts
cd "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.4\bin"
keytool.exe -import -alias SSC -keystore ..\lib\security\cacerts -file "c:\Users\me\Documents\fortify_mycompany_com.crt" -trustcacerts
```

The Fortify Analysis plugin [user guide](https://community.softwaregrp.com/dcvta86296/attachments/dcvta86296/software-security-center-v430/12/1/HP_Fortify_Plugin_IntelliJ_and_Android_4.30.pdf) says that the name of the IntelliJ project must match the name of the project on the Fortify SSC server, and I confirmed that both projects are named "myproject".

When I perform an analysis in IntelliJ using the "Fortify > Advanced Scan" menu option (the "Fortify > Analyze Project" option does not work), it prints out:

> Analysis Completed!: Results available at C:/Users/me/Git/myproject\myproject.fpr`

Then it pops up a dialog box and I enter the following values:

- SSC URL: https://fortify.mycompany.com/ssc
- Username: me
- Password: <mypassword>

Then I get the following error:

> Error communicating with SSC Server: The Fortify SSC server could not be contacted.  Please check your network connection and try again.  If the error persists, please contact your system administrator.

I also see the following exception:

> Exception sending request
>
> org.springframework.ws.soap.axiom.AxiomSoapMessageException: Could not write message to OutputStream: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

The same errors occur if I select the "Fortify > Upload Results to Software Security Center" menu option.

However, when I try to manually upload the results file from the command line using this Fortify utility, it is successful:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Fortify\Fortify_SCA_and_Apps_19.1.2\bin"
fortifyclient.bat uploadFPR -f "c:\Users\me\Git\myproject\myproject.fpr" -url https://fortify.mycompany.com/ssc -project myproject -version "Version 1" -user me -password <mypassword>
```

Why does the IntelliJ Fortify Analysis plugin fail to upload results, when the command line utility works fine?